# I want to get access of shared network folder which requires authentication but I want to do it programmatically,node js

Tags: node.js, smb

I am using smb2 but it is throwing some error and not working with smb2 can anyone help with any open-source option to access the or connect to the shared network folder .I am giving username password and server name but still it's not able to access the server as some ssl error I am getting